# Using WPF keyboard accelerators with international keyboards

Tags: wpf, internationalization, acceleratorkey

I have a WPF app in which I use the standard underscore format (e.g. "Open _File") to associate alt-key presses with my menu items. However, when I set my keyboard to, say, Arabic, it does not work as it seems to be using the higher level representation of the text that was typed (say, "لٌ") instead of the lower level key event (say, `System.Windows.Input.Key.D`).

In my own custom code when I use these lower level events, they work fine with Arabic keyboards (as those keyboards have the English characters alongside the Arabic characters on the keyboard). Is there any way I can make the built in WPF accelerator key code use these lower level events?